# Figuring out how to zip a file/folder using python

Tags: python, zip

I am learning python and I had written code that unzips a folder. So, I pretty much used that same code and rewrote it zip a folder. My problems are when I run the code. The GUI does not come up even though I have no errors. My other issue is that I am not sure if I wrote the def Compress(): code correctly?

```py
import zipfile

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from zipfile import ZipFile

gui = Tk()
gui. geometry('500x500')
gui.title("Compression APP")
        
def compress():
    filecom = filedialog.askopenfile()
    with ZipFile(filecom, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as ext_Zip:
    ext_Zip.write()
    ext_Zip.close()  

 
btn2 = Button(gui, text='file to zip', command= compress).pack()


gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the below code for both zip and un-zip multiple files in a folder,

```
# Import Module
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilenames 
from zipfile import ZipFile 

# Create Object
root = Tk() 
# set Geometry
root.geometry('500*500')

def select_file():
  global file_names
  file_names = askopenfilenames(initialdir = "/",title = "Select File")

# UnZip All Files
def unzip_file():
  for file_name in file_names:
    if file_name.endswith('.zip'):
      with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip:
        zip.extractall()

# Zip The Files
def zip_file():
    with ZipFile('my_python_files.zip','w') as zip:
        for file_name in file_names: 
            zip.write(file_name) 


# Add Labels and Buttons
Label(root, text="Zip & Unzip File", font="italic 15 bold").pack(pady=10)

Button(root,text="Select File",command=select_file,font=14).pack(pady=10)

frame = Frame()
frame.pack(pady=20)

unzip_btn = Button(frame,text="UnZip All Files",command=unzip_file,relief="solid",bg="white",font=15)
unzip_btn.pack(side=LEFT,padx=10)

zip_btn = Button(frame,text="Zip All Files",command=zip_file,relief="solid",bg="white",font=15).pack()

# Execute Tkinter
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't add links to off-site resources unless strictly necessary.